# Suggestions for a small lab server hardware

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for suggestions for a small lab I'm going to have to build. The requirements are as follows

- Virtualization support (so I can run vmware esxi, kvm, hyper-v, etc) - just a couple of lightly loaded VMs, this is not for production.
- At least 8Gb of available RAM (ECC only optional)
- At least 2 (I'd rather have 4) CPU cores
- Power management (IPMI or other, so I can fence) and IP KVM  (iLO/DRAC/IMM/RSA/whatever)
- 2 HDDs (4 - even better)
- Possibility of going up to 4 NICs
- TPM support
- Very small chassis size - going under my desk

I've only come up with HP MicroServer (I'm not sure I can puth an iLO3 *and* an extra NIC in there though). Also found Fujitsu PRIMERGY MX130 S2, but I couldn't google anything about it's use as a hypervisor.

A suggestion to get a small Optiplex came in, but I do need power management and IPKVM, and whether I can put a DRAC in there I'm really not sure.

Are there any additional platforms I've missed? 
What about other solutions to my set of requirements?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure that this is the right forum for hardware advice, however "server" and "small chassis" seems like something of an oxymoron - might be helpful if you said what it was going to be serving, what availaiblity required, why 4 NICs....

Comment: As I've said - this is not for production, just to test out certain features of different platforms, under almost no real load. The extra NICs are there so I can see multipathing and bonding work, the IPMI card is there so I can see HA features that would rely on fencing in action. And IPKVM is there in case I need to access this microlab remotely - I like working from home.

Comment: The "what should I buy" kind of questions is discouraged here at Serverfault. You should rephrase your question as "will the HP MicroServer run ESXi/Hyper-V/whatever virtualization solution?" to prevent it from being closed.

Comment: @syneticon-dj actually, I know the answer to that one :) This is why I'm looking for alternatives - I just want to avoid getting HP if I can.

Comment: In this case, it is off-topic here. You should take a look at the [TX120 S3](http://sp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/ds-py-tx120-s3.pdf), it might be an interesting choice

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

For HP Microserver:
Quickspecs url of HP Microserver: http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13716_na/13716_na.pdf

There isn't ILO but there is an optional management card name"MicroServer Remote Access Card".
You can also add the following optional NIC "HP NC112T PCI Express Gigabit Server Adapter".

Comment: Thanks, I've been through the HP specs, and indeed I seem to be able to add the extra NIC along with a control card. Still open for additional suggestions that are not HP - I'm not much of a fan